# What classifies deformations of group schemes (or Hopf algebras)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, cotangent-complex

The cotangent complex of a scheme classifies its deformations.

That is, if $X$ is a scheme over a field $k$ (with conditions?) and  $\mathbf{T}^*_X\in D^b(\text{QCoh}(X))$ its cotangent complex, the obstruction to a first order deformations existing lives in
$$\text{Ext}^2_X(\mathbf{T}^*_X,\epsilon k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)$$
and if this vanishes, there are $\text{Ext}^1_X(\mathbf{T}^*_X,\epsilon k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2)$ many isomorphism classes of first order deformations.

Similarly for higher order deformations, using $\epsilon^{n-1}k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^n$ (after deforming to order one lower). See Illusie's "Complexe Cotangent" for details over more general bases.

By work of Francis, ["The tangent complex and Hochschild cohomology of $E_n$-rings
"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.0181), there should be a similar version for "noncommutative affine schemes" also, i.e. for associative rings $A$, a.k.a. $E_1$ algebras.

---

**Question:** If we want instead to deform **group schemes** (or their noncommutative versions, **Hopf algebras**), what explicitly is the cotangent complex in some simple examples, e.g. for smooth group schemes $G$?

---

Note that e.g. $U(\mathfrak{g})$ has *no* deformations as an algebra, but *does* have deformations as a Hopf algebra, so e.g. the "group scheme cotangent complex" of $G$ should probably not just be $\mathbf{T}^*_G$. This should be interesting from the point of view of quantum groups etc., and the existence of such a complex presumably follows from  Francis' work (modulo the distinction between Hopf algebras/bialgebras/$E_2$ algebras).

Comment: Illusie considers deformations of group schemes in Chapter VII (which is in Volume 2).